# Fixed : spring mvc queries not found in postman because it is not in the same paquage

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

i am new in spring world and i have implemented a method but when i go to browser and click
http://localhost:8081/SpringMVC/servlet/aaa

i get this error message :

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-12-26T23:16:53.052+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/SpringMVC/servlet/aaa"
}
```

I have tried two methods but still i am facing the same message

here my controller:

```
package t.esprit.controller;


import java.util.List;



import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import tn.esprit.entities.Contrat;
import tn.esprit.entities.Departement;
import tn.esprit.entities.Employe;
import tn.esprit.entities.Entreprise;
import tn.esprit.services.IEmployeService;
import tn.esprit.services.IEntrepriseService;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={
"tn.esprit"})
@RestController
public class RestControlEmploye {

    @Autowired
    IEmployeService empService;
    
    @Autowired
    IEntrepriseService entService;
    
    
/*  @PostMapping("/ajouterEmployer")
    @ResponseBody
    public Employe ajouterEmploye(@RequestBody Employe emp){
        empService.ajouterEmploye(emp);
        return emp;
    }
    
    
    @PostMapping("/affecterEmployerDepartement/{employeId}/{depId}")
    @ResponseBody
    public Employe affecterEmployeADepartement(@RequestParam("user-id")int employeId,@RequestParam("user-id") int depId) {
        return empService.affecterEmployeADepartement(employeId, depId);
    }

    @PostMapping("/ajouterContrat")
    @ResponseBody
    public int ajouterContrat(@RequestBody Contrat contrat) {
        return empService.ajouterContrat(contrat);
    }

    @PostMapping("/affecterContratEmployer/{contratId}/{employeId}")
    @ResponseBody
    public void affecterContratAEmploye(@RequestParam("contratId")int contratId,@RequestParam("employeId")int employeId) {
        empService.affecterContratAEmploye(contratId, employeId);
    }

    @PostMapping("/affecterContratEmployer/{employeId}")
    @ResponseBody
    public String getEmployePrenomById(@RequestParam("employeId")int employeId) {
        return empService.getEmployePrenomById(employeId);
    }

    @GetMapping("/getNombreEmployeJPQL")
    @ResponseBody
    public long getNombreEmployeJPQL() {
        return empService.getNombreEmployeJPQL();
    }

    

    @GetMapping("/getAllEmploye")
    
    public List<Employe> listemploye() {
        List<Employe> list = empService.listemploye();
        return list;
    }

    @PostMapping("/affecterEmployeDepartement")
    @ResponseBody
    public void affecterEmployeDepartement(@RequestBody Employe user, @RequestBody Departement dep) {
    empService.affecterEmployeDepartement(user, dep);
    }

    
    @GetMapping("/getAllEmployeByEntreprise")
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Employe> getallEmployebyEntreprise(@PathVariable("identr")int identr) {
    return empService.getallEmployebyEntreprise(identr);
    }

   
    @PutMapping("/mettreAjourEmailByEmployeId")
    @ResponseBody
    public void mettreAjourEmailByEmployeId(@RequestParam("email")String email, @RequestParam("employeId")int employeId) {
        empService.mettreAjourEmailByEmployeId(email, employeId);
    }
    
    
    @GetMapping("/getEmployeById/{employeId}")
    @ResponseBody
    public Employe getEmployeById( @PathVariable("employeId") int employeId) {
        return empService.getEmployeById(employeId);
    }

    
    @DeleteMapping("/deleteEmployeById/{id}")
    @ResponseBody
    public void deleteEmployerById(@RequestParam("id") int id) {
        empService.deleteEmployerById(id);
    }

    
    
    @DeleteMapping("/deleteEmployeContractById/{id}")
    @ResponseBody
    public void deleteEmployerContractById(@RequestParam("id") int id) {
        empService.deleteEmployerContractById(id);
    }
    */
    
    /*@GetMapping("getAllEmployeNames")
    public List<String> getAllEmployeNamesJPQL() {
        List<String> list = empService.getAllEmployeNamesJPQL();
        return list;
    }*/
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/aaa", method= RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8")
    public List<String> getAllEmployeNamesJPQL() {
        List<String> list = empService.getAllEmployeNamesJPQL();
        return list;
    }
    
}
```

i do not understand what is happening , i launched my application as a spring boot application and tried man of those different queries but i still get the same result , for idea my database and apache server are active and working fine and the my repositories working fine too , just the urls none worked for me!

here my application properties file:

```
#Server configuration

     server.servlet.context-path=/SpringMVC
     spring.mvc.servlet.path=/servlet
     server.port=8081
     ### DATABASE ###
     #spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
     spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/timesheet?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCo
     spring.datasource.username=root
     spring.datasource.password=
     ### JPA / HIBERNATE ###
     spring.jpa.show-sql=true
     spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
     spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
    
    
     #Web configuration
     spring.mvc.view.prefix=/views/
     spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
    
     #logging configuration
     logging.level.tn.esprit.service=debug
     logging.level.tn.esprit.repository=warn
     logging.level.root=INFO
     logging.pattern.console=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %-5level - %logger{36} - %msg%n
     logging.file=C:\logs\springboot.log
```

what am i missing???? why postman and my browser can not catch the queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add @RequestMapping annotation on top of your class and this parameter should be "/SpringMVC/servlet/{function extension}". For this function "aaa" as you show.

```
import java.util.List;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"tn.esprit"})
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/SpringMVC/servlet")
public class RestControlEmploye {

@Autowired
IEmployeService empService;

@Autowired
IEntrepriseService entService;

@RequestMapping(value="/aaa", method= RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8")
public List<String> getAllEmployeNamesJPQL() {
    List<String> list = empService.getAllEmployeNamesJPQL();
    return list;
  }
}
```

Comment: the same problem , i have this in my console 020-12-26 23:55:00 - INFO  - o.s.b.w.e.tomcat.TomcatWebServer - Tomcat started on port(s): 8081 (http) with context path '/SpringMVC'
2020-12-26 23:55:00 - INFO  - tn.esprit.TimesheetApplication - Started TimesheetApplication in 1.583 seconds (JVM running for 93.984)

Comment: Can you share the log output after send a request on the Postman?

Comment: {
    "timestamp": "2020-12-27T00:24:36.527+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/SpringMVC/servlet/getAllEmploye"
}

Comment: ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-12-27 00:30:31 - INFO  - o.s.b.w.e.tomcat.TomcatWebServer - Tomcat started on port(s): 8081 (http) with context path '/SpringMVC'
2020-12-27 00:30:31 - INFO  - tn.esprit.TimesheetApplication - Started TimesheetApplication in 5.831 seconds (JVM running for 6.358)    Here my console

Comment: fixed by adding this rest controller in the same package with the main java class

Comment: yes it should definitely be like this, you should add the answer as edit at the top